# Left Outer Join To Get All Rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm working with an access database and I have some tables set up like this.

```
Table1(Table1Id, Field1, Field2, ...)
Table2(Table2Id, Table1Id, AuditDate, Field1, Field2, ...)
```

I am trying to select every record in Table1, and those in Table2 with the latest AuditDate. If there is no entry in Table2 to tie back into Table1, I just want to populate a row of what is in Table1 and a bunch of empty fields where the data from Table2 would come from. Here is the query I have so far.

```
SELECT Table1.TableId, 
       Table1.Field1, 
       Table1.Field2, 
       Table2.Field1, 
       Table2.Field2 
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TableId = Table2.Table1Id 
WHERE Table2.AuditDate = (SELECT MAX(AuditDate) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.TableId = Table2.Table1Id)
```

The problem with this is that it only returns two records. There are only two entries in Table2 but I want it to return a row of data for every record in Table1 as well instead of just the ones that find a match in Table2.

Comment: going to need a SQL fiddle to work through this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
WHERE Table2.AuditDate = ...
```

In cases where no `Table2` entry exists, `AuditDate` will be NULL. So you need to test for that:

```
WHERE Table2.Table2Id IS NULL OR Table2.AuditDate = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess that if you remove the outer you would get every entry from table 1.

Edit: but if you have more entries in Table 2 than in Table 1 it will still be a problem.
Maybe try a Full JOIN?